# Cannot text from iPhone to friend on Note 8

Tags: iphone, messages, sms, android

This is essentially [a repost of a previous question I asked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252548/my-iphone-cant-text-friends-android-but-my-wifes-iphone-can) a while back, but a few things have changed and I never got a working answer, so I thought I should post again.

My friend has been on iPhone for a while (in case you read the old question, after the Note 7 recall fiasco he went back to iPhone so the problem went away until now) and has now switched to a Note 8 running Android.  He is currently able to text me fine, and it shows up in Messages as an SMS in the existing chat history we've had for ages (green bubbles now, not blue as before).  My replies however, are never received by him.  The do not fail to send, they are just never received.

Here are some more facts:

- I am the only person he has this problem with, other users both on Android and iOS can receive and reply to his texts without incident.
- He was on Sprint when he had the Note 7, but is on Verizon now with the Note 8.  I am
  also on Verizon.
- My wife had an iPhone 4S at the time he had the Note 7, but we both currently have iPhone SEs (hers on iOS 9, mine on iOS 10)
- I am able to make and receive phone calls to/from him, so his phone number is not blocked in my phone.
- With my wife's SIM card in my phone, I am unable to text
  him.  With my SIM card in her phone, I am able to text him without
  incident.
- I had previously deleted his contact from my phone entirely (losing all the chat history to date) but nothing changed.

We are at our wits ends with this but refuse to let it go.  There's got to be some explanation for this, we just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: is his number still registered in iCloud? (if it is, when you message him the baloon is blue)

Comment: The message will not be blue because he is not on iOS.  All messages to/from him are SMS now.

Comment: he may still be registered to icloud: https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage/

Comment: I'l ask him to check again, but we already went through this whole thing last time with his Note 7.  Also remember, it is *only* my phone that can't text him.  Any other iOS device - phone, iPad, even a Mac - has no trouble at all.  Even my phone with a different SIM, can't text him.

Comment: As I suspected, he has already done this and Apple confirms that his phone number is *not* registered.

Comment: :) pesky problem... if you tap on your friend name at the top of the message flow, are all the information of his contact ok? (i don't remember if IOS 10 highlights the contact info used in the last message). Also, when you put your sim in your wife's phone, you didn't also log into icloud, right?

Comment: His contact seems to be just fine, and I had even previously deleted it entirely just to verify that wasn't the problem - it wasn't.  As for the SIM, I didn't explicitly log into iCloud after swapping, but I never logged out either.  Not sure how that's relevant here so feel free to explain if I may be missing something.

Comment: the problem seems connected to your iPhone, so what I think is the something in your settings or in your iCloud data keeps identifying his contact as the old one.

Comment: Everything does seem to point to my phone or account, I agree.  So the question becomes - how is this possible?  Nobody else's iPhone has this problem with him, and this happened even after I completely deleted his contact information (sacrificing all our chat history in the process) and treated him as a completely unknown contact.